# Grails - Spring Security / Social - Facebook plugin setAccessToken and getAccessToken

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security, spring-social

I just got done walking through the install instructions on this page:
http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook

I choose AuthUser for the User domain object name and AuthRole as my Role domain object name. In all other questions I choose the defaults or put in my Facebook App ID or Facebook App Secret.

At the end of the process I have a AuthUser as my User. I also have a FacebookUser that implements FacebookUserDomain.

When I try to run the app it tells me I haven't implemented getAccessToken or setAccessToken in my FacebookUser. This is being required by the FacebookUserDomain interface. Is this normal? Does the documentation need to be completed? What is the correct way to handle this?

**UPDATE**
Here is the FacebookUser class code I tried to use to solve the problem.

```
class FacebookUser implements FacebookUserDomain {
  long uid
  String secret
  String session
  String email
  String accessToken

  static belongsTo = [user: AuthUser]

  static constraints = {
    uid unique: true
  }

  public String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken
  }

  public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken
  }
}
```

Also getting this error:Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

Configuring Spring Security Facebook ...
ERROR: There is no dao configired for Facebook Auth
ERROR: Stop configuring Spring Security Facebook
2011-12-19 19:17:30,261 [main] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Unknown colum
n 'deactivate_code' in 'where clause'
could not execute native bulk manipulation query
2011-12-19 19:17:30,496 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error execut
ing bootstraps: No property found for name [facebookId] for class [class lmfirst
.AuthUser]
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException: No property foun
d for name [facebookId] for class [class lmfirst.AuthUser]
        at lmfirst.UtilService.createMayor(UtilService.groovy:20)

Comment: note: accepted the answer but still having issues with the Spring Security piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make get/set for accessToken, as it automaticaly added by Groovy itself. Having `String accessToken` is enought

As about Facebook Auth dao - did you executed `grails s2-init-facebook`? It generates default Dao implementation for you, and register it at `conf/spring/resources.groovy`

Comment: Ok. Might be running into a Spring Security thing here. I try to get to my main "home page" for the site and I get a 500 error. org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Invalid signature. What am I missing? Do I need to allow a non-authenticated request to get to this page? How do I do that?

Comment: Should have said before that I dropped the two methods. And the default FacebookAuthDaoImpl was there. Not sure why I had a problem the first time.

Comment: Seems like the 500 Bad Credentials error is originating from the FacebookCookieFilter. I'm not sure why it is looking for the cookie at this point since the page I'm trying to request is "open to everyone" by the fact it doesn't have a @attribute on the controller method, right? +1

Comment: hm, you right, probably it must just skip invalid cookie. btw, it's not a common situation when user have facebook cookie for your site with invalid signature. Are sure that you've configure plugin with correct facebook credentials?

Comment: Credentials are correct. Not sure why my Account controllers index method is authenticated. Shouldn't it skip checking anything at this point? I haven't even shown the facebook connect button?